# Load python dict from a non-valid json string

Tags: python, json

Consider the following json object:

```
> a = {u'service': u"Lulu's Bakery"}
```

Good. Now let's print it:

```
> s = str(a)
> print s
{u'service': u"Lulu's Bakery"}
```

The question is: how to smartly load the json object from that string?

The simple approach with `json.loads(s)` obviously won't work here since `s` is not a valid json string.
And the approach with multiple manual replacements doesn't seem to be appealing enough because for example I'd prefer to avoid differentiating `u's` part in `u'service'` and `Lulu's` contexts.

Any simple solution?

Comment: firstly do `s = json.dumps(a)` and then do `json.loads(s)`

Comment: yeah, that would work, however I already have a bunch of bad strings that need to be converted to json objects...

Comment: Can you also upvote my answer? As it full fills the requirement of the question.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, I would gladly accept your answer if I were asking how to dump and load python dicts. However I was rather asking about the way to load a dict from a non-valid json string. This task is a bit different, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval`

Some purists hate the use of `eval`, and it is **unsafe** to run on untrusted input (imagine if some evildoer put `os.system("rm -rf *")` in the file with the strings. evaling that would delete your files).  But this is a correct use case for eval. `eval` will convert the string you have back to a python object.  If you want the JSON for that python object you can then further use `json.dumps`

```
In [1]: s = '''{u'service': u"Lulu's Bakery"}'''

In [2]: s
Out[2]: '{u\'service\': u"Lulu\'s Bakery"}'

In [3]: x = eval(s)

In [4]: x
Out[4]: {u'service': u"Lulu's Bakery"}

In [5]: import json

In [6]: json.dumps(x)
Out[6]: '{"service": "Lulu\'s Bakery"}'
```